# CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED does not disable deprecated warnings

Tags: gcc, cmake

I run `cmake` as follows:

```
cmake . -G Ninja -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/libs/QT6.5d -DCMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED=OFF
```

but get the following warning while building my project with GCC12:

```
  /usr/include/c++/12/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]
     32 | #warning \
        |  ^~~~~~~
```

why doesn't `CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED` take an effect?

Running cmake with `-Wno-deprecated` also does not help.

```
cmake . -G Ninja -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/libs/QT6.5d -Wno-deprecated
```

Comment: The option `-Wno-deprecated` for `cmake` and variable `CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED` are about warnings from **CMake**. For control warnings from the compiler use appropriate **compiler** options. E.g. `add_compile_options(-Wno-deprecated)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_WARN_DEPRECATED.html) controls *CMake* warnings (those emitted by `message(DEPRECATION ...)`), and passing `-Wno-deprecated` to CMake is an alias for setting this variable to `OFF`.

Your deprecation warning is issued by the *compiler*, and you need to pass the `-Wno-deprecated` flag to the compiler. One way to do this is to use [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html):

```
target_compile_options(<target> [PRIVATE|PUBLIC] "-Wno-deprecated")
```